# How to display the true range of my parameters on a contour plot in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab, range, contourf

I want to display the values of a function *Z = Z(x,y)* in the range *(x_min, x_max)* and *(y_min, y_max)* using the contourf function in Matlab 2015a. Here is my code:

```
N = 20;
x_min = 20;
x_max = 40;
y_min = 40;
y_max = 80;
x = linspace(x_min, x_max, N);
y = linspace(y_min, y_max, N);
[X,Y] = meshgrid(y,x);
Z = X.*Y;
for i = 1:N
    for j = 1:N
        Z(i, j) = 10*i+j;
    end
end
contourf(Z);
colorbar
```

And this is the plot I get:
[image]

How can I show the true range of x and y (*20<=x=<40* and *40<=y=<80*)?

Answer (score 4):

A look at the [fantastic MATLAB documentation](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contourf.html) reveals that you can supply three arguments to `contourf`, namely the X, Y, and Z values.

```
N = 20;
x_min = 20;
x_max = 40;
y_min = 40;
y_max = 80;
x = linspace(x_min, x_max, N);
y = linspace(y_min, y_max, N);
[X,Y] = meshgrid(y,x);
Z = X.*Y;
for i = 1:N
    for j = 1:N
        Z(i, j) = 10*i+j;
    end
end
contourf(X,Y,Z);
colorbar
```

This will give you properly labelled tick marks:

[image: contourf]